# Filtering by an AD Security Group in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I have an ASP.NET application developed in Visual Studio 2010 using ver 4 of the .NET Framework that uses the native Authentication controls.  I have wired up the site using the Active Directory membership provider.

My connection string looks like this:

```
connectionString="LDAP://MYDC-004/DC=company,DC=corp,DC=pvt"
```

This works well, as the login page works properly, and any user that exists in AD can log in with their credentials.

However, I ***only*** want to allow users that are in *one specific Security Group* to be able to log in.  I know where the security group (called "GR-DwgDep-Admins") is located in AD Organizational Units, so I came up with this modified connection string:

```
connectionString="LDAP://MYDC-004/CN=GR-DwgDep-Admins,OU=Groups,OU=Division,DC=company,DC=corp,DC=pvt" />
```

When I attempt to log in (and I am definitely in this group), the error I get is "User objects cannot be created in the specified container."

Is my syntax incorrect?  Or am I doing this the wrong way conceptually?  I would really prefer to do this via the connection string setting, since that way the existing .NET login control will work with it as-is.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions anyone has.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the groups that a user belongs too and check if it matches the group that you want to give access too.

First you need to load in the user, then you need to loop through the "memberOf" collection and check if they belong to the specified group.

```
           //Get connectionstring from web.config and initialize directory entry to search for groups user belongs to
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ADConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            //Specify that we want to find the groups
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de, "(objectCategory=group)");

            //Filter by user and specify what data to return
            ds.Filter = String.Format("(&(SAMAccountName={0}))", model.UserName);
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
            ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");

            //Loop though all results
            foreach (SearchResult sr in ds.FindAll())
            {
                //Get the properties available and loop through "memberof"
                DirectoryEntry desr = sr.GetDirectoryEntry();
                ResultPropertyCollection myResultPropColl = sr.Properties;

                //Get a key
                foreach (string myKey in myResultPropColl.PropertyNames)
                {
                    //Check the key that we are using "memberof"
                    if (myKey.ToLower() == "memberof")
                    {
                        //Loop through all items for given key
                        foreach (System.String myCollection in myResultPropColl[myKey])
                        {
                            //Check if we have a match
                            if (myCollection.Contains("Web - Internal Admin"))
                            {
                                //Success                                   

                                de.Dispose();
                                desr.Dispose();
                                //Do something
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

For the first line, I am getting my AD connection string from my web.config

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ADConnectionString"].ConnectionString
```

web.config

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://ua.local/DC=ua,DC=local" />
```

I am then getting the groups and filter it by specific username. Then I specify the return values for sAMAccountName and memberOf. It is not nesecary in this example to get the sAMAccountName.

```
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de, "(objectCategory=group)");

        //Filter by user and specify what data to return
        ds.Filter = String.Format("(&(SAMAccountName={0}))", model.UserName);
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
```

The rest is pretty much straight forward to understand. Loop through the result and check for the "memberof" key. Once found, use the "memberof" key and loop through its values and check if it matches the group you are requiring.

```
if (myKey.ToLower() == "memberof")
```

Check this links for more information:
[Searching for groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180909%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Remy - I ended up doing something similar, but I like your method better.  I will experiment with what you have done here and post back with any additional questions.  Thank you for your detailed response!

Comment: I forgot to mention that because I am searching by sAMAccountName which is unique for the domain, correct me if I am wrong, but we could skip the foreach loop and just change ds.FindAll() to ds.FindOne() and wrap everything in a try catch final statement. Good Luck!